# Package mathptmx Error: The symbols $\jmath$, $\amalg$ and $\coprod$ (mathptmx) are not available

Tags: mathptmx

I used a latex template to write an article. I need to use the symbol `$\coprod$`, but there exist a

> Package mathptmx Error: The symbols \jmath, \amalg and \coprod are not available with this package.

I tried to use package `txfonts`, but it does not work. how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Are you trying with `\prod` or `\coprod`?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the `mathptmx` package, I suggest you load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages. (They are the successors to the `txfonts` package.) Happily, `newtxmath` provides definitions for `\jmath`, `\amalg`, and `\coprod`.

Comment: ERROR:"newtxmath.sty" not found,is there any other methods?

Comment: @crazie exactly which latex installation (and version) are you using? Might want to consider upgrading

Comment: @crazie - Which TeX distribution do you use? The `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages have been part of both TeXLive and MikTeX for about five years.

Answer (score 2):

Import just those glyphs from the cm font family. EDITED to make an importation macro,

```
\imCYsym[<mathtype>]{<fontfamily>{<glyph number>}}{<macro name>}
```

Default `<mathtype>` is `\mathord`.

If more than one symbol needs to be imported from the same font family, and to avoid redeclaring a duplicate font family, one could simply use this macro for importing additional symbols, once a font is declared:

```
\newcommand\alsoimCMsym[4][\mathord]{\DeclareMathSymbol{#4}{#1}{CM#2}{#3}}
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% =============================================
%Import symbols from font cm without importing the whole package
% =============================================
\newcommand\imCMsym[4][\mathord]{%
  \DeclareFontFamily{U} {#2}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{#2}{m}{n}{
    <-6> #25
    <6-7> #26
    <7-8> #27
    <8-9> #28
    <9-10> #29
    <10-12> #210
    <12-> #212}{}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{CM#2} {U} {#2}{m}{n}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{#4}{#1}{CM#2}{#3}
}
\newcommand\alsoimCMsym[4][\mathord]{\DeclareMathSymbol{#4}{#1}{CM#2}{#3}}

\imCMsym{cmmi}{124}{\CMjmath}
\imCMsym[\mathop]{cmsy}{113}{\CMamalg}
\imCMsym[\mathop]{cmex}{96}{\CMcoprod}
\alsoimCMsym[\mathop]{cmex}{97}{\CMbigcoprod}
\begin{document}
%$abcdefg$ plus: $\jmath$, $\amalg$ and $\coprod$\par % CAN COMPARE WHEN mathptmx NOT LOADED
Math ptmx $abcdefg$ plus: $\CMjmath$, $\CMamalg$ and $\CMcoprod$\par
Additional symbol from cmex font family$\CMbigcoprod$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the shape of the regular "j" in `ptmx`?  that might make a difference.

Comment: @barbarabeeton the tail is similar, the top is not [curly on the shown CM `j`, seriffed on the ptmx (times) `j`[.  But what can be done, short of finding a different font to import?

Comment: the `\jmath` is essentially just an undotted j, in the appropriate style.  so somehow arranging to obliterate the dot (maybe by clipping it as a graphic, and also adjusting the height) could be a desperate approach.  of course, finding a suitable font with the actual glyph is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want `\coprod`, as `\prod` gives no problem whatsoever. You can fake it by reflecting `\prod` along the vertical axis and some box trickery for adjusting the position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\coprod}{\mathop{\text{\fakecoprod}}}
\newcommand{\fakecoprod}{%
  \sbox0{$\prod$}%
  \smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr.9625\depth-\dp0}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\prod$}}}%
  \vphantom{$\prod$}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
\coprod_{i=1}^n
\prod_{i=1}^n
\]
\[
\coprod\prod x
\quad
\textstyle \coprod\prod x
\quad
\scriptstyle \coprod\prod x
\quad
\scriptscriptstyle \coprod\prod x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]